# Trying to print the contents of a vector to a text file using visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, text-files

I'm trying to get used to using vectors to store information and I need to write the contents of a vector to a file.  My code stores the pixel information from inside a box with a variable width and height.  I'm trying to test out printing the vector by putting the number 255 in each position of the vector.  When I run my code and create the file, I only have 0's.  Is there something I'm missing?  Here is my code:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <math.h> 
   #include <fstream>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h> 
   #include <strstream>
   #include<vector>
   using namespace std;

    vector<int> ROIPixels;
    G_BoxWidth = 250;
    G_BoxHeight = 100;
    int TopBox = G_BoxY;
    int LeftBox = G_BoxX;
    int RightBox = G_BoxX + G_BoxWidth - 1;
    int BottomBox = G_BoxY + G_BoxHeight - 1;
    int vColMax = G_BoxWidth;
    int vLineMax = G_BoxHeight;
    ROIPixels.clear();
    ROIPixels.resize(vColMax*vLineMax*4, 0); //I'm multiplying by 4 because 
                                             //i'm using a bitmap
    iCol = LeftBox;
    while (iCol <= RightBox)
    {
        iLine = TopBox;
        while (iLine <= BottomBox)
        {

            ROIPixels.push_back(255);


            iLine++;
        }
        iCol++;
    }

    if (CaptureImage_Flag == 2)
    {
        //## Save arrImage1 to file "arrImage2.dat"
        string OutFileName = "ROIPixels.dat";
        ofstream OutFile(OutFileName.c_str(), ios::out);
        if (!OutFile)
        {
            cerr << "Error: " << OutFileName << "could not be created."
                << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < vColMax*vLineMax * 4; ii++)
        {
            if (ii / 4. == (int)(ii / 4.))
            {
                OutFile << (int)(ROIPixels[ii]) << endl;
            }
        }
        OutFile.close();
        exit(1);
    }
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions for my code.  Thank you.

Comment: [Minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) aren't just for our benefit, they're a vital coding skill. Start with simple code that works, then build up.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `resize()` puts `vColMax*vLineMax*4` zeros in your vector.

Then `push_back` adds a bunch of `255` values, without replacing or removing the zeros.

Finally, you print out the first `vColMax*vLineMax*4` items, which are the zeros from `resize()`.

Comment: Hi.  How would I write the 255 values into the position of each zero?  I was trying to iterate through the nested while loop and be able to store the corresponding pixel info in each spot of the vector.

Comment: @JetPirate: Calculate what position you want the new value to occupy, then (if you named the position "index") the statement `ROIPixels[index] = 255;` will replace one of the existing values instead of growing the vector.